# Cell content click WPF datagrid VB.net

Tags: wpf

Is there any event like cellContent clicked in WPF datagrid? I want to open the custom dialogue box on specific column cell content click or cell enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by EventSetter in Style for DataGridCell.
For example:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="MyEventHandler" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```